# Besides disabling items, what is the best way to prevent duplication glitches on tekkit servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-tekkit

I have had many issues with people on my tekkit multiplayer server using Tekkit items to illegally obtain or duplicate items.  So my question is: *How do I prevent my players from exploiting the bugs in tekkit?*

Of course, the easy way out would be to flat out ban items as you discover the glitches.  The problem with this is that silent players who are 50,000 blocks out are not going to be accused of hacking.  The players who lay lowest would be able to use the glitches until somebody spills the beans on the glitch.  Obviously, as a server owner, I don't want people being able to use **any** glitches that will give them an advantage over players who are playing legitimately.

I have several issues however:

- If players are seen hacking or glitching, server administrators are not on 100% of the time and I am only one person.  I cannot handle dozens of people screaming my name in chat because they have a hunch that somebody is doing illegal things.
- Another issue is Tekkit fly hackers.  It's very hard to tell if somebody is using a hacked client versus simply using a fly ring.  Since fly-disabled is set to false, people can float forever and the server will not even do so much as log the event.

My players do not appreciate it when I ban or disable certain items as many items used for glitches are useful for other legitimate reasons.  **I am looking for an answer that provides as many possibilities as possible and objectively presents them.**  A high quality post to solve this problem will be beneficial to all Tekkit server owners as there is no true place (that I have seen) that addresses this question thoroughly.

Comment: Are you open to the possibility that there's no existing thorough answer to this yet because it might be impossible?

Comment: Yeah, I use that a lot to catch the obvious fly hackers

Answer (score 1):

There are too much bugs in tekkit to prevent this, and it would be nearly impossible to program a plugin which checks if someone exploits any single one of these many bugs. You could make a plugin which warns you if someone gets very much items in a very short period of time, but this would only prevent excessive buguse. Against the flyhack, you could use [this mod](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/tekkit-restrict/), which should prevent flyhacking without disabling the fly ring.

Comment: Link to mod is dead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Essentials, you could do `/invsee` to secretly see other people's inventory (in real time too!) In addition to that, if you find something, just stand in front of a lava pit and do the command. Then take the trash out like you would with your normal inventory (take a stack and toss it outside the inventory).

Comment: Why was this downvoted?